# Adding item to List<>

Tags: c#, .net

Cleary I'm missing something here but I cannot see

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>().Add(new Item() { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2});
```

Error message is

> Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `List<>`

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `object initializer` for a list. You can't call `Add` like that **because it returns `void`, not the `List` itself**. Try this:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
                   {
                       new Item { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2 }
                   };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that on two lines:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
Items.Add(new Item() { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2});
```

The reason you are getting the error is that [`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method doesn't return anything and  your `Items` is expected to be filled by what is returned from the right hand side.

Here is the signature for the Add method.

```
public void Add(
    T item
)
```

Answer (score 0):

or like this

```
       List<Item> Items = new List<Item>{
             new Item() { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2}
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Add with object initializer. **List.Add return void** which is not expected when you are initialising your list. Use this instead:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>
{
   new Item { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2 }
};
```

Or if you still want to use Add then you can split the code in two lines as explained by Habib.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a single line then use [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

such as:

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item> 
     { new Item() { Code = "12223", ExGroup = 2 } };
```